# How to run unit test in maven with different JVMs (e.g. HotSpot, OpenJ9, SAP JVM etc.)

Tags: maven, jvm, maven-surefire-plugin

Is there a convenient way to run maven surefire unit test suite sequentially or in parallel with completely different JVMs like HotSpot, OpenJ9 or Azul and aggregate the test results in an holistic report?